# Serial Camera recommendations?

Tags: fpga, video, camera, intel-fpga

I have an altera stratix iv FPGA, given to me by my professor to do a project that involves video processing.

The ports I have to work with are RS232 (female), an IDE port and several SATA ports, and several ethernet ports.

Can anyone recommend some good cameras for hooking up to the board for video?  I need a pretty high quality camera, but I'd like to keep it under $80.

Anything would be helpful, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Shopping questions are closed.

Comment: ok... Can you point me to somewhere I'm 'allowed' to ask this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethernet is about your only sane option in that case - get an ethernet surveillance type camera.

Be warned, there's a lot of work involved just to get an image in before you do any image processing!

Comment: Thank you!  This is very helpful.  Of course the difficulties you highlight are fairly troubling.  I might start looking into finding some kind of expansion board now.